# How to use date +%u with a given day to find the day of week number

Tags: bash, date

Is there way of using $date +%u to figure out the day of week number for a particular given day? I will be using this line in forecasting estimations.

For example:

```
DOW=Monday
day_no=`date "$DOW" +%u`    # Should output 1
echo "$DOW is $day_no"
```

Or should I just use if or case method:

```
if [ "$DOW" == "Monday" ]
then
   day_no=1
elif [.....]
then
 ....
```

The first method is 3 lines, the if or case method would be 20+ lines.

I am using Bash.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass `$DOW` to the `-d` flag, which reads a description of the time to be formatted, it will give you what you want:

```
day_no=$(date -d "$DOW" +%u)
```

Note that this assigns 1 to Monday and 7 to Sunday.

Comment: This works in Linux, but not in OSX or FreeBSD. The OP hasn't mentioned his operating system -- it's important to produce portable answers.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to achieve this.

If you want to use something specific to bash, I'd suggest an array.  In bash 4, an associative array might be used like this:

```
declare -A days='([Monday]="1" [Tuesday]="2" etc...)'

DOW="Monday"

day_no=${days[$DOW]}
```

If you're in bash 3 (in OSX for example), you might have to roll through a non-associative array.

```
declare -a days='([1]="Monday" [2]="Tuesday" etc...)'

DOW="Monday"

for _ in "${!days[@]}"; do
  if [ "${days[$_]}" = "$DOW" ]; then
    day_no=$_
    break
  fi
done
```

If you want to handle this with the `date` command, it's important to know what platform you're using, as `date` behaves differently in different operating systems.  The following might work for you:

```
case $(uname -s) in
  Linux)        day_no=$(date -d "$DOW" '+%u') ;;
  *BSD|Darwin)  day_no=$(date -j -f '%A' "$DOW" '+%u') ;;
  *)
    echo "ERROR: I don't know how to do this in $(uname -s)." >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Note that one of the array-based solutions *might* very well be the faster than a solution that involves calling an external program (`date`).